# Как сделать inline-кнопки из базы данных?

Tags: python, база-данных, aiogram, бот, telegram

Пишу бота на `Python` (`aiogram3`). Есть база данных, в которой хранятся значения  "название" и "цена". Суть в том, что когда клиент нажимает на кнопку узнать цену, должен появиться список с `inline`-кнопками с названиями товаров, а после нажатия на нужную кнопку, бот должен отправить цену этого товара.

Вопрос в том, как сделать эти `inline`-кнопки. Пока есть понятие, что нужно создать массив с этими кнопками с помощью цикла, но как прописать функцию и `handler` - непонятно.

Вот приблизительный вид бота:

[image: Вот приблизительный вид бота]

Answer (score 0):

Функция генерирования inline-кнопок:

```
def genmarkup(data):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.row_width = 1
    for i in data:
        markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(f'{i[1]} | {i[2]}', callback_data=f'send_price_{i[0]}'))
    return markup
```

Где i[1] - название, i[2] - цена, i[0] - ID в базе данных.
Если у вас другие значения порядка в базе - измените.

Обращение:

```
data = cur.execute(f'SELECT * FROM products').fetchall()
await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, 'Все товары:', reply_markup=genmarkup(data))
```

Где 'SELECT * FROM products' - ваш запрос.

Отследить на что нажато можно следующим образом:

```
    @dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data.startswith('send_price_'))
async def process_callback_license_check(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    id = callback_query.data.replace('send_price_', '')
    result = cur.execute(f'SELECT product_price FROM products WHERE product_id = {id}').fetchone()[0]
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, result)
```